# DBMS for POS software

Tags: c#, database

I want to develop a POS application in .NET (C#) that would be used to rent items. I have a good idea of what will be done and the famous question that I have is about the DBMS that I should use. I would like to use MySQL database.

The question is: If some places use only one computer (no network, no internet connection), can I use a MySQL database in local? Do I need to install MySQL server on all thoses computers to be able to use such a database? I know SQLite but I'm not sure if the limitations can cause problems in the future... I also looked at SQLServer Express versions.

(I must consider that other point of sales are using multiple computers and more transactions so there I can't put sqlexpress or sqlite)

So can anybody suggest me what I should do in that situation?

Thanks

Comment: Would you be centralizing the data from all the local machines at some point?

Comment: Why do you think you can't use SQL Express... you will save your self tons of pain and have a much better security model.

Comment: 1- Yes, the data will be centralized in a MySQL database
2- Because Sql Express has some limitations... size max:10gb I think for the 2008 version, I know it's a lot but (maybe?) not enough after several years

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to use MySQL in localhost - and it would need to be installed on each local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).  If you are sharing a database between several computers you should just be able to install the [MySQL client components](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

As for which database you want to use, I would highly suggest [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/).  The security model and tooling is much better.  There is nothing stopping you from using SQL Express as a shared database server until you out grow it.

[SQL Express Redistribution EULA](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express/redistregister.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

POS systems like Open bravo [POS software](http://multipost.ca/) where special user types and hardware devices support are required.ou can use sharing a database between several computers for using sql.